# Stop Raspbian (Raspberry Pi OS) from asking if I want to execute or open a .desktop file

Tags: raspbian

I wrote a .desktop thing and my raspberry pi keeps asking if I want to open or execute the file, is there a way to stop this, I've looked in the properties but nothing there. Maybe a line to add to the .desktop file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have just used the information in the answer by @PMF to finally avoid the confirmation that popped up when I clicked on the .desktop file I made 2 years ago for gnome-terminal.

Comment: Dear @Community Bot - it is not at all 'hard' to tell exactly what this person is asking.

Answer (score 4):

This option is a bit hard to find. Open a file manager window, go to "Edit->Settings" and check the box that says "Disable queries when opening executable files" (or similar).

Unfortunately, I only have a german screen shot, but you should find the option.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate this:

[image]

Here is the English version of PCManFM options.

Change this to checked/ticked:

[image]